# SQL server apply Month or year condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL server, I have a column in it with datatype DateTime, I want to get data on specific month or year, ie

```
Select * from Table where datejoined='07'//Getting July Data
```

or

```
Select * from Table where datejoined='2013'//Getting 2013 Data
```

I have tried this,but its comparing the minutes of time

```
select * from Table where datejoined like '%07%'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  Year(DATEJOINED) = 2013
```

or:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE 
WHERE  Month(DATEJOINED) = 7
```

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi don't forgot to accept the answer so the answered person will get right rewards..... .

Answer (score 2):

Maybe following solutions are complicated but the will give you better performance (this means Index Seek) if you have indexes. These examples are based on [AdventureWorks2008R2](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/59211) database:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME;
PRINT 'Test #1: By YEAR';
DECLARE @Year SMALLINT;
SET     @Year=2005;
SET     @StartDate=CONVERT(CHAR(4),@Year)+'0101';
SET     @EndDate=DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@StartDate)+1,0)

SELECT @StartDate AS StartDate,@EndDate AS EndDate
SELECT  h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
WHERE   h.OrderDate>=@StartDate AND h.OrderDate<@EndDate;

PRINT 'Test #2: By MONTH';
DECLARE @Month TINYINT,@FromYear SMALLINT,@ToYear SMALLINT;
SET     @Month=7;
SELECT  @FromYear=YEAR(MIN(h.OrderDate)),@ToYear=YEAR(MAX(h.OrderDate))
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader h

SELECT @FromYear AS FromYear,@ToYear AS ToYear;

SET     @StartDate=CONVERT(CHAR(4),@Year)+'0101';
SET     @EndDate=DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,@StartDate)+1,0);

WITH N10(Num)
AS
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
)
SELECT  y.*,h.OrderDate,h.SalesOrderID
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.StartDate,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,x.StartDate)+1,0) AS EndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(CHAR(4),@FromYear-1+n.Num)+RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@Month),2)+'01') AS StartDate
        FROM    N10 n
        WHERE   n.Num<=(@ToYear+1-@FromYear)
    ) x
) y INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader h ON h.OrderDate>=y.StartDate AND h.OrderDate<y.EndDate
```

Results:

```
Test #1: By YEAR
StartDate               EndDate
----------------------- -----------------------
2005-01-01 00:00:00.000 2006-01-01 00:00:00.000

OrderDate               SalesOrderID
----------------------- ------------
2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 43659
...
2005-12-31 00:00:00.000 45037


Test #2: By MONTH

FromYear ToYear
-------- ------
2005     2008

StartDate EndDate                 OrderDate               SalesOrderID
--------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------
20050701  2005-08-01 00:00:00.000 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000 43659
...
20080701  2008-08-01 00:00:00.000 2008-07-01 00:00:00.000 74159
```

Execution plans:

[image]

Comment: Note: Every of those two `Index Scan` operators (`Query 2`) from the second execution plan will read from the root page towards leaf pages just one record within every level of `IX_SalesOrderHeader_OrderDate` index. This query will work for max. 10 years. If OP need a greater timeframe then `N10` CTE needs modifications.

Comment: Thank you t-clausen.dk. I try to write SARG predicates (when possible).

Answer (score 2):

Use to_char() function:

```
Select * from Table where to_char(datejoined,'dd')='07'     //Getting July Data

Select * from Table where to_char(datejoined,'yyyy')='2014'      //Getting 2014 year Data
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DATEPART`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) seems ideal for this:

```
Select * from Table where DATEPART(month,datejoined) = 7

Select * from Table where DATEPART(year,datejoined) = 2013
```

Whilst there are dedicated functions for obtaining `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY`, there are no such equivalents for the time portions of a datetime. `DATEPART`, in contrast, can extract any of the components of a `datetime`. It can also extract, for example, the weekday.

Comment: Why use DatePart for month or year?

Comment: @Gidil - consistency?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating on a column like that can give a terrible performance if used on a large table.

Use this for year:

```
SELECT * FROM table where datejoined >= '20130101' and datejoined < '20140101'
```

Use this for month if you have performance problems, it will compare on all dates between '1950-07-01' and now

```
;with cte as
(
 SELECT convert(date, '1950-07-01', 121) d1, 
        convert(date, '1950-08-01', 121) d2
 UNION ALL
 SELECT dateadd(year, 1, d1), dateadd(year, 1, d2) 
 FROM cte
 WHERE d1 < getdate()
)
SELECT * FROM table t
join cte
ON datejoined >= d1 and
datejoined < d2
```